# Making Form with VB .NET 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to create a program which:

1. Downloads a web page on a regular interval (every 10 minutes)
2. Finds a specific element on the page (an HTML `div` element with an ID of `rekto`)
3. Checks the value of that element, and then acts on it (if it's `0`, do nothing and wait for the next cycle, and it if it's `1`, launch `notepad.exe`)

Here's the code I have so far:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://controlry.tr.gg/control.htm")
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'Me.Hide()
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    WebBrowser1.Refresh()

    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("rekto").GetAttribute("value")
    If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What I can understand from the description is that: 1) You need to refresh a HTML page every `N` minutes  2) Check the value of a HTML Element. 3) Do something with this `value` if it's not `empty`. But what this Element contains and what you want to do with it is unclear. The question's Title is also unclear. What does *Make Form* mean?

Comment: `Refresh()` is done in the background and returns immediately. If you want to get data from the website you need to wait for the page to load completely. Subscribe to the [`WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted) and get the element from there.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.   You've told us what you want, but not what your problem is.

Comment: I'm a bit confused what is the problem, what are the challenges faced, what are the errors?